# failed to save the state of the virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I keep getting the error `failed to save the state of the virtual machine` `Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) \` in `VirtualBox 5.0.12` on a Linux (Kubuntu) host with a `Windows 7` guest. Why would this be? Other guests (Win10) seem to be abler to save their current state just fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing solved this for me: there was a lack of free space on the drive the saved state/hdd image was meant to be saved.

As soon as there was enough space there (and on root/home for me) the problem went away